# React Native Expo Android WebView

Tags: android, react-native, webview, android-webview, expo

I'm working on a React Native app using Expo.
Trying to load a WebView using "react-native-webview".

this is the WebView element:

```
<WebView style={styles.container}
            source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com/" }}
            ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
            cacheEnabled={false}    
/>
```

I'm running the app on devices, on iOS it works well, but on Android it doesn't load the site and I'm getting an Error.

```
Encountered an error loading page, Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "code": -1,
  "description": "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS",
  "loading": false,
  "target": 25,
  "title": "",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/",
}
```

Expo version - 3.19.2

Android version - 5.0

Couldn't find a working solution, does anyone know what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shahid pointed out, this seems to be an **Android issue**, which is solved in androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0 However, the latest expo version still uses 1.1.0 so I'm afraid there is currently **no fix** for it and we'll have to wait for the expo team.

Some people have resolved the issue by **downgrading** their SDK Version and the Expo Client App. I'm not sure why that has worked though. Perhaps you could try that.

Answer (score 1):

this is Android issue, which is solved in androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0, currently, you may use 1.1.0

You need to upgrade expo version. it might be solved your problem

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using the latest SDK version(37.0.0), just ran expo upgrade to ensure that all my packages are set to the correct version. but still problem not solved